# How to get memory info without sudo command on bash

Tags: bash, memory, ram

No idea how to create a bash script, without using sudo, that shows Memory Info like 8 x 16384 MB DIMM-1600 MT/s Samsung. number of memory + size of each + type + manufacturer

Comment: You could use `sudo`

Comment: How would you do it _with_ using `sudo`?

Comment: I have a task that displays (the quantity of Ram + size in MB + type + manufacturer).
I should run the script test.sh -m
Output:
8 x 16384 MB DIMM-1600 MT/s Samsung

Comment: You may want to start looking around for things like `dmidecode`.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov OP says "without using sudo" and your comment is "You could use sudo". How is that relevant/useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```bsh
sudo lshw -class memory | sed -n '/-bank/,$p' | sed -n '/cache/q;p' | egrep "bank|description|product|size|clock|vendor"
     *-bank:0
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 3600 MHz (0.3 ns)
          product: XXXXX
          vendor: CRUCIAL
          size: 16GiB
          clock: 3600MHz (0.3ns)
     *-bank:1
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 3600 MHz (0.3 ns)
          product: XXXXX
          vendor: CRUCIAL
          size: 16GiB
          clock: 3600MHz (0.3ns)
     *-bank:2
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 3600 MHz (0.3 ns)
          product: XXXXX
          vendor: CRUCIAL
          size: 16GiB
          clock: 3600MHz (0.3ns)
     *-bank:3
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 3600 MHz (0.3 ns)
          product: XXXXX
          vendor: CRUCIAL
          size: 16GiB
          clock: 3600MHz (0.3ns)
```

The first `sed` omits everything in the input unless `-bank` is found, the second truncates the output as soon as `cache` is found. egrep only outputs the strings which contain any of the words separated by the pipe symbol. Masters of shell could probably reduce these three processing commands down to one but I'm not so good.

You could just run `sudo lshw -class memory` and see everything.